# Click to reveal phone number

Tags: jquery

I have a directory with users phone numbers. I don't what to print the entire numbers so that people don't copy them. I want to use a jquery (or any language) to hide last 4 digits so that users can click each number to reveal full number. Also, i want to only reveal the number clicked. Clicking another number will automatically close the previous one. Pls I need help. All the once I saw are not doing this.

Below is a sample of the code which works. However, when I click on a number, it reveals all the numbers in the page for all subscribers.
I want to reveal only one number one at a time. Pls help. I'm not very good at jquery or javascript.

```
//
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".flip").click(function() {
$(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
div.panel,p.flip {
text-align: center;
}
div.panel {
widht: 50%;
height: 100px;
display: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php   
foreach($result->result() as $row) {
echo '<tbody><tr>
<td>'.$row->fullname.'</td>
<td>'. $row->bloodgroup.'</td>
<td><div class="panel"><p>'. $row->Phone.'</p></div>
<p class="flip">Show Phone Number</p></td>
<td>'. $row->Phone2.'</td>
<td>'. $row->email.'</td>
<td>'. $row->city.'</td></tr></tbody>'; }
?>
</body>
</html>
//
```

Comment: Show use the code you have tried.

Comment: it's a long code. I don't know how to post it due to character limit

Comment: Do you know http://www.sscce.org/? And did you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LhsLyqyh/) that might help you out as an example.

Basically it cuts the last 4 letters off, puts it in an array and binds a click handler to it, so that it can get back which phonenumber belongs to it and then replaces the phonenumber with the original one.

**HTML**

```
<p class="phonenumber">+1 202 224 0173</p>
<p class="phonenumber">+1 202 717 0178</p>
<p class="phonenumber">+1 202 505 0179</p>
<p class="phonenumber">+1 202 645 0183</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var phonenumbers = [];
    $(".phonenumber").each(function(i) {
        phonenumbers.push($(this).text());
        var newcontent = $(this).text().substr(0, $(this).text().length - 4)
        $(this).text(newcontent);
        $(this).bind("click", function() {
            if ($(this).text() == phonenumbers[i]) {
                $(this).text(phonenumbers[i].substr(0, phonenumbers[i].length - 4));
            } else {
            $(".phonenumber").each(function(x) {
                if ($(this).text() == phonenumbers[x]) {
                   $(this).text(phonenumbers[x].substr(0, phonenumbers[x].length - 4));
                }
            });            
            $(this).text(phonenumbers[i]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/LhsLyqyh/)

**EDIT: so in your case you want to change the p class where the phone number is stored, like this:**

http://jsfiddle.net/LhsLyqyh/2/

Comment: The content (phone numbers) are dynamically printed from the database. Only one LOC to show. '. $row->Phone2.' therefore <p class="phonenumber">+1 202 224 0173</p>
<p class="phonenumber">+1 202 717 0178</p>
<p class="phonenumber">+1 202 505 0179</p>
<p class="phonenumber">+1 202 645 0183</p> might not work. I want to see if there is a way to add id to the code so it appends it to each number as unique id

Comment: Just make sure to put the content in a HTML object `(a div, a p, etc.)` with the class `phonenumber` and it'll work as you see in the demo.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this demo, it might clear it up more for you. (click on the red phone number, then on another one or on the same one) http://jsfiddle.net/LhsLyqyh/2/

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much. But pls where do i add the jQuery code? Do i have to include <script> </script>? Thanks

Comment: Yes you have to put it in between `<script></script>`, under `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. It works now just as I wanted.

Comment: @DaanHeskes this method works like a charm, but is it possible to use the click to reveal function but still allow the number itself to be clickable?

Comment: @Ben Hi, great it helped. Please check the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LhsLyqyh/5/)

Comment: @DaanHeskes thanks - much appreciated. Finally - is there a way to have click to reveal displayed instead of the partial number. Just in case some users don't necessarily realise.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on from Daan's code above (TY sir), this will dynamically hide the last 3 characters of all anchor tags within a page, that have a class of `click-reveal-phone-number`, and replace them with '...' - as to help the user realise that there is more of the number to reveal.

**Added bonuses:** This will trim the white space from the start and end of the phone number, if any. This will open a users's default phone-call application on both mobile and desktop.

On-Load: `0414 123 ...` |
On-Click: `0414 123 456`

HTML

```
<a 
  href="tel:+61-414-123-456" 
  class="click-reveal-phone-number"
>
  0415 123 456
</a>
```

JS

```
  const allClickRevealNumbers = $("a.click-reveal-phone-number");

  allClickRevealNumbers.each(function (i) {
 
    const rawNumber = $(this).text()
    const rawNumberStartEndSpacesRemoved = rawNumber.trim();
    const rawNumberEllipsed = rawNumberStartEndSpacesRemoved.replace(rawNumberStartEndSpacesRemoved.substr(rawNumberStartEndSpacesRemoved.length - 3), '...'); 
    
    phonenumbers.push($(this).text());
    $(this).text(rawNumberEllipsed);

    $(this).bind("click", function (e) {

      if ($(this).text() === phonenumbers[i]) {
        $(this).text(rawNumberEllipsed);
      } else {
        allClickRevealNumbers.each(function (x) {
          if ($(this).text() === phonenumbers[x]) {
            $(this).text(rawNumberEllipsed);
          }
        });
        $(this).text(phonenumbers[i]);
      }

    });

  });
```